# Phalcon keep a model persistant in all the controllers?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, phalcon

my website application is mostly model around a User Model which has all the key data that needed for most of the times.

Once the user is logged into the website I would like to keep it as a  persistent variable across all the controllers. How do i achieve this as i cannot use session to hold a class object of Type Model.

My application is based on phalcon. However any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to write a simple class for user authentication & other user data manipulation, i wrote this `Component` and using in my project :

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component;

class Auth extends Component {

    public function login($credentials) {

        if(!isset($credentials['email'],$credentials['password'])) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if($this->isAuthorized()) {
            return true;
        }

        $user = Users::findFirstByEmail($credentials['email']);

        if($user == false) {
           //block user for seconds

           return false; 
        }
        if($this->security->checkHash($credentials['password'],$user->password) && $user->status == 1) {
            $this->_saveSuccessLogin($user);
            $this->_setUserLoginSession($user);
           return true; 
        } else {

            return false;
        }


    }

    public function isAuthorized() {
        return $this->session->has('auth');
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->session->remove('auth');
        return true;
    }

    public function user($key = null) {
        if(!$this->isAuthorized()) {
            return null;
        }

        if(is_null($key)) {
            return $this->session->get('auth');            
        } else {
            $user = $this->session->get('auth'); 
            return array_key_exists($key, $user) ? $user[$key] : null;
        }
    }

    private function _saveSuccessLogin(Users $user){
        $userLogin = new UserLogins();

        $userLogin->user_id = $user->id;
        $userLogin->ip = $this->request->getClientAddress();
        $userLogin->user_agent = $this->request->getUserAgent();
        $userLogin->dns = gethostbyaddr($userLogin->ip);

        if(!$userLogin->save()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private function _setUserLoginSession(Users $user) {
        if(!$user) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->session->set('auth',array(
            'id' => $user->id,
            'firstname' => $user->firstname,
            'lastname' => $user->lastname,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'role_id' => $user->role_id
        ));

        return true;
    }
}
```

And in my `services.php` added into `DI` with this code :

```
$di->setShared('auth', function () {
    return new Auth();
});
```

So when i want to get user info i use this :

```
$this->auth->user('email')
```

Also you can add more functionality to this component & modify it.

I hope that's useful for You.

Comment: this looks like user object model is turn into a session array and requesting it from session when needing it .. i was wondering keeping the model as it is in the memory and accessing it when needed via controllers ..etc

Comment: So you can use `DI` with User model like this :
`$di->setShared('user', function () {
    return new Users::findFirstById(1);
});`
and you can change `1` with your logged user id.

Comment: $di->setShared how this function can be called inside the controller ? as i get a error :Service 'user' wasn't found in the dependency injection container

Comment: you can use `$this->user->id` in your controllers. does this code get error for you?

Comment: yes, bt to set the user model to the di, i have to do that in a controller, (if i set it on a index.php user may not be already logged in), so setting the user as di service needs to be done on the controller itself as a shared service for all the controllers ..thats where the problem is

Comment: OK, i think you only have to write your own class (like my `auth`) to handle this feature. it means you add your class into `DI` then when user logged in, you set user id & use your user model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use memcached and save it as key => value:
userId => serialized User model